# javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type RestClient

Tags: java, quarkus, quarkus-rest-client

I have a Quarkus application v2.15.3.Final using Java 17. The application does have one API endpoint which fetches the data using the third-party API and processes them. To hit the third-party API I am using the RestClient. However when I start the application using `quarkus dev` application failed to start and result in the below error

```
Caused by: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type com.abc.xyz.zoho.ZohoRestClient and qualifiers [@Default]
    - java member: com.abc.xyz.zoho.client.ClientServiceImpl#zohoRestClient
    - declared on CLASS bean [types=[com.abc.xyz.zoho.client.ClientServiceImpl, java.lang.Object, com.abc.xyz.zoho.client.ClientService], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=com.abc.xyz.zoho.client.ClientServiceImpl]
```

**ClientServiceImpl.java**

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import lombok.extern.jbosslog.JBossLog;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.config.inject.ConfigProperty;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.inject.RestClient;

/**
 * Manages methods for zoho clients.
 */
@ApplicationScoped
@JBossLog
public class ClientServiceImpl implements ClientService {

  @ConfigProperty(name = "zoho.refresh-token")
  private String refreshToken;

  @ConfigProperty(name = "zoho.client-id")
  private String clientId;

  @ConfigProperty(name = "zoho.client-secret")
  private String clientSecret;

  @Inject
  @RestClient
  ZohoRestClient zohoRestClient;

  @Inject
  ClientRepository clientRepository;


  @Override
  public void processClients(String token) {
     ...
     zohoRestClient.generateAccessToken(refreshToken, clientId, clientSecret,
            Constant.ZOHO_GRANT_TYPE);
     ...
  }


}
```

**ZohoRestClient.java**

```
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.inject.RegisterRestClient;

@RegisterRestClient(baseUri = "https://accounts.zoho.in", configKey = "zoho-api")
@ApplicationScoped
public interface ZohoRestClient {

  @POST
  @Path("/oauth/v2/token")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  AccessToken generateAccessToken(
      @QueryParam("refresh_token") String refreshToken,
      @QueryParam("client_id") String clientId,
      @QueryParam("client_secret") String clientSecret,
      @QueryParam("grant_type") String grantType
  );

}
```

I do not have any config for hitting the third-party API in the application.properties file.

If I do comment @Inject for ZohoRestClient and only keep @RestClient annotation then I am able to start the application but when I do hit the API I am getting the

**ZohoRestClient.generateAccessToken(String, String, String, String)" because "this.zohoRestClient" is null**

Comment: The source code looks correct, but the error mentions `Unsatisfied dependency for type com.abc.xyz.zoho.ZohoRestClient and qualifiers [@Default]`, so for some reason, the `@RestClient` qualifier is lost. Do you perhaps have some extension that does annotation transformations, or something like that?

Comment: Hi @Ladicek Thanks for the response. No, I do not have any other config for hitting the external API.

Comment: @Ladicek If I do comment Inject for ZohoRestClient and only keep RestClient annotation then I am able to start the application but when I do hit the API I am getting the

ZohoRestClient.generateAccessToken(String, String, String, String)" because "this.zohoRestClient" is null

Comment: did you try with a more recent version of branch 2.x just to exclude a problem of `2.15.3.Final`? or downgrade to java-11 just for test?

Comment: Yeah, this just proves that `@RestClient` is not treated as a qualifier, which is _weird_. Do you have a reproducer somewhere? Also verify that you have a dependency on the RestClient Quarkus extension (`quarkus-rest-client-reactive` if you're using RESTEasy Reactive, or `quarkus-rest-client` if you're using classic RESTEasy).